# Lower bounds for 3SUM with a free cache

Tags: lower-bounds

Consider the 3SUM problem: given a set $S$ of $n$ numbers identify $x$,$y$,$z$, s.t $x + y = z$. It is believed that the simple $O(n^2)$ algorithm is the best possible; reductions from 3SUM have been used to prove lower bounds for other problems assuming 3SUM is hard [Patrascu 2010].

Is it possible to prove that a small amount $n^\delta$ ($\delta < 1$) of free cache does not help for 3SUM? (An algorithm can store information in the cache and access it for free while accesses to regular RAM cost 1.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the cache supposed to be read-only information chosen prior to the input (i.e., "non-uniform advice")? Or can one both read and write to these $n^{\delta}$ bits, at literally no cost? Using "almost-linear" hashing, you can reduce 3SUM on $n$ numbers to $O(t^2)$ instances of 3SUM on $O(n/t)$ numbers. So if you can really access this $n^{\delta}$ space *for free*, then by setting $t$ so that $(n/t)\log n \approx n^{\delta}$ you get a $n^{2-\varepsilon}$ 3SUM algorithm, as the $O(t^2)$ instances would take about $O(n/t)$ time each.

Answer (score 7):

Well, sure, it's **possible**.  But since we basically don't know how to prove that *anything* is hard, it doesn't look easy.

In the mid 90s I proved [an $\Omega(n^2)$ lower bound for 3SUM](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/linsat.html) in a variant of the linear decision tree model; my proof was later simplified by [Ailon and Chazelle](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/lindegen-jacm.pdf).  This model of computation has nothing corresponding to "memory"; the running time of an algorithm is defined simply as the worst-case number of (generalized) comparisons.  So adding a cache won't break these lower bounds; to beat $O(n^2)$ time, you have to do some non-obvious *computation* with the data in the cache.